# How to create login in shiny using Shinyauthr libarary without displaying main panel in R?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyauthr

Currently, I have my shiny app in condition such that I am able to enter information in the sidebar panel, and able to display the output in the `mainpanel`. Next, I would like to create a login screen using [shinyauthr](https://github.com/PaulC91/shinyauthr/blob/master/README.md) library, such that user 1 should only able to see the side bar panel information, and the Output table should only be displayed when user2 login. For this,I am trying to follow the code mentioned on the main page of [shinyauthr](https://github.com/PaulC91/shinyauthr/blob/master/README.md). My issue is that whenever I try to hide mainpanel using ## tag. Below error will get display.

*Note: I am new to Shiny, provide explanation with external link or code*

```
"Error in sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(div(id = "form", textInput("name",  : 
  argument "mainPanel" is missing, with no default"
```

**Code that takes in UserInput and display in Mainpanel:**

```
#Storing data on Local Machine
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

outputDir <- "responses"

# Define the fields we want to save from the form
fields <- c("name", "address","used_shiny", "r_num_years","select")

#Which fields are mandatory
fieldsMandatory<-c("name","address")


labelMandatory <- function(label) {
  tagList(
    label,
    span("*", class = "mandatory_star")
  )
}

appCSS <-
  ".mandatory_star { color: red; }
#error { color: red; }"


saveData <- function(input) {
  # put variables in a data frame
  data <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=1,ncol=0))
  for (x in fields) {
    var <- input[[x]]
    if (length(var) > 1 ) {
      # handles lists from checkboxGroup and multiple Select
      data[[x]] <- list(var)
    } else {
      # all other data types
      data[[x]] <- var
    }
  }
  data$submit_time <- date()

  # Create a unique file name
  fileName <- sprintf(
    "%s_%s.rds", 
    as.integer(Sys.time()), 
    digest::digest(data)
  )

  # Write the file to the local system
  saveRDS(
    object = data,
    file = file.path(outputDir, fileName)
  )
}

loadData <- function() {
  # read all the files into a list
  files <- list.files(outputDir, full.names = TRUE)

  if (length(files) == 0) {
    # create empty data frame with correct columns
    field_list <- c(fields, "submit_time")
    data <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(field_list), nrow = 0))
    names(data) <- field_list
  } else {
    data <- lapply(files, function(x) readRDS(x)) 

    # Concatenate all data together into one data.frame
    data <- do.call(rbind, data)
  }

  data
}

deleteData <- function() {
  # Read all the files into a list
  files <- list.files(outputDir, full.names = TRUE)

  lapply(files, file.remove)
}

resetForm <- function(session) {
  # reset values
  updateTextInput(session, "name", value = "")
  updateTextInput(session, "address", value = "")
  updateCheckboxInput(session, "used_shiny", value = FALSE)
  updateSliderInput(session, "r_num_years", value = 0)
  updateSelectInput(session,"select",selected = 'NULL')
}



ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::inlineCSS(appCSS),

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Data Collection & Feedback"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      div(id='form',
          textInput("name", labelMandatory("Name"), ""),
          textInput("address",labelMandatory('address'),""),
          checkboxInput("used_shiny", "I've built a Shiny app before", FALSE),
          sliderInput("r_num_years", "Number of years using R",
                      0, 10, 0, ticks = FALSE),
          selectInput("select","select",choices = c('a','e','i')),
          actionButton("submit", "Submit",class='btn-primary'),
          actionButton("clear", "Clear Form"),
          downloadButton("downloadData", "Download"),
          actionButton("delete", "Delete All Data"),


          shinyjs::hidden(
            span(id = "submit_msg", "Submitting..."),
            div(id = "error",
                div(br(), tags$b("Error: "), span(id = "error_msg"))
            )
          )

      ),  
      shinyjs::hidden(
        div(
          id = "thankyou_msg",
          h3("Thanks, your response was submitted successfully!"),
          actionLink("submit_another", "Submit another response")
        )
      )  
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("responses")
    )
  )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {
  # Enable the Submit button when all mandatory fields are filled out
  observe({
    mandatoryFilled <-
      vapply(fieldsMandatory,
             function(x) {
               !is.null(input[[x]]) && input[[x]] != ""
             },
             logical(1))
    mandatoryFilled <- all(mandatoryFilled)

    shinyjs::toggleState(id = "submit", condition = mandatoryFilled)
  })



  # When the Submit button is clicked, save the form data
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    #saveData(input)
    #resetForm(session)
    shinyjs::disable("submit")
    shinyjs::show("submit_msg")
    shinyjs::hide("error")

    tryCatch({
      saveData(input)
      shinyjs::reset("form")
      shinyjs::hide("form")
      shinyjs::show("thankyou_msg")
    },
    error = function(err) {
      shinyjs::html("error_msg", err$message)
      shinyjs::show(id = "error", anim = TRUE, animType = "fade")
    },
    finally = {
      shinyjs::enable("submit")
      shinyjs::hide("submit_msg")
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$submit_another, {
    shinyjs::show("form")
    shinyjs::hide("thankyou_msg")
  })   
  observeEvent(input$clear, {
    resetForm(session)
  })

  # When the Delete button is clicked, delete all of the saved data files
  observeEvent(input$delete, {
    deleteData()
  })

  # Show the previous responses in a reactive table ----
  output$responses <- renderDataTable({
    # update with current response when Submit or Delete are clicked
    input$submit 
    input$delete

    loadData()
  })


  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename= "data.csv",

    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(loadData(), file, row.names = FALSE, quote= TRUE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `req()` condition to only render the responses table in the mainPanel if the logged in user is user2.

```
# Show the previous responses in a reactive table ----
  output$responses <- renderDataTable({
    # only render table if user2 is logged in
    req(credentials()$info$user == "user2")

    # update with current response when Submit or Delete are clicked
    input$submit 
    input$delete

    loadData()
  })
```

Check out the [package readme](https://github.com/PaulC91/shinyauthr) for a full app example that uses `req()` to conditionally show a table based on a login condition.